# File upload to a Google Cloud Storage Signed URL in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Can someone help me with the code to upload a file to a Google Cloud Storage Signed URL in Python, preferably using the Requests library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python) on Github. It shows a portable way to achieve this using PyCrypto and requests.

Note that, if your app is running on App Engine, you can easily sign the string using the App Engine Identity service and its `sign_blob()` method, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-gae).

Answer (score -2):

Here is [sample code](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url/blob/master/sign_url.py) for AppEngine app using `sign_blob()` as mentioned in LundinCast's answer. I verified that it works.